# How to deep clone with prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

How to clone object tree, maintaining prototype chain? `structuredClone` doesn't work:

```js
class Some {
  hi() { return 'hi' }
}

const a = new Some()
console.log(a.hi())

const b = structuredClone(a)
console.log(b.hi()) // => TypeError: b.hi is not a function
```

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) help? (There are **lots** of them.) (And yes, `structuredClone` has [several limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone), including that it doesn't try to maintain the prototype chain.)

Comment: You want a universal clone that will handle *everything* possible? Or you just want to be able to clone specific class(es)? The latter is way more feasible. There are *many* things that can go wrong trying to clone any arbitrary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to reliably clone all JavaScript objects, for a variety of reasons, three of which are:

- Some objects contain data in "internal slots" that are not accessible to your code
- Method properties of objects (including accessor properties — [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)) may have a link to the object they were created on (their "home" object), depending on how they were created. That cannot be accessed, and thus copied, by your code
- Method properties (again including accessors) may also *close over* data that you can't directly access and thus can't clone

I'm sure there are others, those are just the three that immediately come to mind.

Since it can't be done reliably in the general case, *any* solution you go with is going to have limitations, just like [`structuredClone` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone) (as you've seen, it doesn't try to preserve prototype chains). They might be *different* limitations you can tailor to your use case, but there will be limitations.

For a shallow clone, you can get *close* with:

- [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get the prototype of the source object
- [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to creates an object with a specific prototype (the one from above)
- [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) to get the descriptors of all of the object's own properties,
  and
- [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to create matching properties on the target object

Something along these lines:

```
function clone(obj) {
    const newObj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    Object.defineProperties(
        newObj,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
    );
    return newObj;
}
```

```js
function clone(obj) {
    const newObj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    Object.defineProperties(
        newObj,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
    );
    return newObj;
}

class Some {
    hi() {
        return "hi";
    }
}

const a = new Some();
console.log(a.hi());

const b = clone(a);
console.log(b.hi());
```

Or if you like things really condensed:

```
const clone = (obj) => Object.defineProperties(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

A couple of notes on that example:

- It does a *shallow* clone (if the source has a property referring to an object, both copies will refer to the same object), but you could make it deep by cloning any property values that are objects (lots of examples in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)). If you do, you'll want to remember any clones you make in a `Map` keyed by the source object so you can reuse them if you see the same source object again (and you'll want to seed the `Map` with the object you're cloning as the key and your new object as the value), to handle self-references and such.
- Because it clones methods and accessors, you may get the odd behavior I warned about above

Here's an example of *one* of the ways that would fall down (private properties):

```js
function clone(obj) {
    const newObj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    Object.defineProperties(
        newObj,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
    );
    return newObj;
}

class Some {
    #message = "hi";
    hi() {
        return this.#message;
    }
}

const a = new Some();
console.log(a.hi());

const b = clone(a);
console.log(b.hi());
```

You can't fix that, private properties are fully private.

Here's another example (methods that close over constructor locals [could be accessors, too]):

```js
function clone(obj) {
    const newObj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    Object.defineProperties(
        newObj,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
    );
    return newObj;
}

class Some {
    constructor(message) {
        this.getMessage = () => message;
        this.setMessage = (newMessage) => {
            message = newMessage;
        };
    }
    hi() {
        return this.getMessage();
    }
}

const a = new Some("a");
console.log(a.hi());    // a

const b = clone(a);
console.log(b.hi());    // a - so far so good, but:

// Setting message on `a`...
a.setMessage("x");
// ...spookily sets it on `b`:
console.log(b.hi());    // x?!
```

But depending on your use case, it may be sufficient, or a nudge the right way toward building something sufficient.

Comment: `clone()` is not deep here. Any properties with objects as values will end up with the original and the clone sharing the reference. The `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` + `Object.defineProperties()` is still probably the best universal approach possible but it does have its limitations: "cloning" a getter/setter property might be weird depending on what it references. Cloning might also need to go up the prototype chain to make independent copies of the objects, if ancestors hold references that should not be shared.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, I did mention it was shallow with notes about making it deep if they need it. :-) *""cloning" a getter/setter property might be weird depending on what it references."* Yes, that's a good thing to point out. It's true of methods in general, not just getters and setters. I'll beef up the warnings a bit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any built-ins for a deep clone. You could write the clone methods yourself:

```js
class Some {
  greeting = 'hi'

  hi() { return this.greeting }

  clone() {
    const clone =  new Some();
    clone.greeting = this.greeting;
    return clone;
  }
}

const a = new Some()
console.log(a.hi())

const b = a.clone()
console.log(b.hi())
```

Supposedly it seems lodash `cloneDeep` method will preserve classes, although this [isn't documented](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/clone-deep/).

```js
class Some {
  greeting = 'hi'

  hi() { return this.greeting }
}

const a = new Some()
console.log(a.hi())

const b = _.cloneDeep(a);
console.log(b.hi());
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is occurring because the `structuredClone` method in JavaScript is designed for cloning data, not complex objects with methods or prototype chains. It's typically used for serializing and deserializing data for transfer between different contexts, such as web workers or for storage in IndexedDB.
a is an instance of the Some class, which has a hi method. When you call a.hi(), it correctly returns 'hi'.

However, when you use `structuredClone` to clone `a` into `b`, it creates a new object that is essentially a shallow copy of `a`. This means it only copies the data properties of `a` and not its methods or prototype chain. As a result, `b` does not have the `hi` method, hence the error when you try to call `b.hi()`.

If you want to clone an object along with its prototype chain in a simple way, you can create a new instance of the object's constructor and then copy over its properties. Here's an example:

```
class Some {
  hi() { return 'hi' }
}

const a = new Some();
console.log(a.hi());

//Object.getPrototypeOf(a) gets the prototype of a.
//Object.create() creates a new object with that prototype.
//Object.assign() copies the properties from a to the new object.

const b = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)), a);
console.log(b.hi()); // Output: hi
```

**Deep cloning**, here it is:

```
class Some {
  hi() { return 'hi'; }
}

function deepCloneWithPrototype(obj) {
  if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return obj; 
  }

  if (obj instanceof Date) {
    return new Date(obj);
  }

  if (obj instanceof RegExp) {
    return new RegExp(obj);
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    const arrCopy = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      arrCopy[i] = deepCloneWithPrototype(obj[i]);
    }
    return arrCopy;
  }

  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  const objCopy = Object.create(proto);

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      objCopy[key] = deepCloneWithPrototype(obj[key]);
    }
  }

  return objCopy;
}

const original = {
  nested: {
    value: 42
  }
};

const shallowClone = Object.assign({}, original);
const deepClone = deepCloneWithPrototype(original);

shallowClone.nested.value = 100;
deepClone.nested.value = 100;

console.log(original.nested.value); // Output: 100
console.log(shallowClone.nested.value); // Output: 100
console.log(deepClone.nested.value); // Output: 100
```

Comment: This cloning would still work for relatively simple data. Notably, none of the values in the objects should be objects, otherwise both the original and the clone will share the same reference to the object.

Comment: When using this method for cloning objects, it's important to note that it creates a shallow copy. This means that if the object you're cloning contains nested objects, those nested objects will not be cloned—they will still be referenced by both the original and the clone.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77353699/438273) makes some good points about trade-offs. What's in your actual class will strongly inform the best approach.

If you already understand the restrictions of the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) and are confident that the data within your instance can be cloned — and simply want to maintain the prototype chain as your question title suggests…

> How to deep clone with prototype chain?

…in order to make methods, getters, etc. available on the cloned object — then you can combine [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) with some static `Object` methods to accomplish that goal:

- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

```js
const copy = Object.assign(
  Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(originalInstance)),
  structuredClone(originalInstance),
);
```

[Code in JS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&inlineSources=true&inlineSourceMap=true&isolatedModules=true&filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbAptA3gKGtAlgOz2QCdoBedaFKMAc2QC5oAiACxyegF8BuDLaEPBoAKAJTp+2YPDwR4IZADpBIgC5sIi-ISKKqEWslG9snPtjqrKyanTETs2IslUBXInmjqcm7cT02BnQmXBhmGNKyVmBk0IQA7nBIyGK8YMpCqdAA9NmkAHzMbEy8GNkAVOXQAAKqAJ4ADqhoCCic0OXZETIQVgBGsQDyfQBWyMCqipAQODR4wvzDYxOKwM5gqilL45OWAApE8KpHjciDAGbCYKKiADT8vUSuE+7IACYAwoKEV3cYxnw+hkRMYcnlCqx2BggX5dPpDLFWMgQIIStDgVlcgUisjURh0ipMeCilDurJ5EpCel4XRQViIcUyXIFBigTSjNwwdikSj4Ew+JFmZTMtsVj4rloCMRbtAYVKiDdOfToOcwCAIMgMEA)

```js
class Some {
  inner = { message: "hi" };

  log() {
    console.log(this.inner.message);
  }

  get message() {
    return this.inner.message;
  }
}

const a = new Some();
a.log(); //=> "hi";

const b = Object.assign(
  Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)),
  structuredClone(a),
);

b.log(); //=> "hi"
b.inner.message = "hello";
b.log(); //=> "hello"
a.log(); //=> "hi"

console.log(a.message); //=> "hi"
console.log(b.message); //=> "hello"

console.log(Object.is(a.inner, b.inner)); //=> false
```